# What could make a noise when I decelerate with a manual gearbox?

Tags: engine, noise, renault, gears

### Update 06/23/2014

One week later, this noise is now very, very loud, even when I don't decelerate. As soon as I put the 5th gear and clutch, it vibrates whether I accelerate or not. It's like if the gearbox was going to explode.

---

### The problem

I have a french car (Renault Scénic) with a manual gearbox (that's not the problem ;) ).

When I'm in 5th gear - and only 5th - and I remove my foot from the accelerator pedal, there is a continuous very loud noise, like if all the engine block was vibrating.

So, to reproduce the issue:

- 5th gear
- Any speed
- Foot off the accelerator

To make it end, I either:

- Accelerate (even if accelerate a very very little, the noise ends as soon as the engine drives the gearbox)
- De-clutch

Can you guess where the noise comes from?
Could it be the little metal bar under the card, linked to the gear lever that could vibrate against another part only when it's pushed far to the left (5th gear)?
Could it be the gearing inside the gearbox?

Comment: I take it this is a new noise? Did it suddenly go from nothing to noisy, or did it gradually get louder? How many miles are on the vehicle?

Comment: Your gear level question is interesting: have you tried damping the vibrations of the gear lever while the noise is occuring?  If it's the gear lever, even the lightest torque will change the sound.

Comment: @Paulster2: It went suddenly from nothing to a little noisy, and then it slowly went to very noisy. 330.000km (~205000 miles).

Comment: @BobCross I tried moving it around (without changing gears) while it was in 5th gear. The noise doesn't change at all, so it might not be the lever or the bar underneath the car.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a bearing going out in your transmission. With your mileage, it wouldn't be unheard of. Not for sure, but would probably take it to a tranny shop to have it looked at.

Comment: @Paulster2, now turn it into an answer....

Answer (score 2):

Considering everything you've said to this point, it sounds like you have a bearing going out in your transmission. With your mileage, it wouldn't be unheard of. I would definitely have a respectable transmission shop in your area take a look at it. If it is a bearing, they can replace just the bearing (and any other worn part such as synchros and clutch -- "soft parts") at the same time. Even if these parts are not completely bad, labor would not be much more because everything is being pulled apart anyway.

Comment: I've edited my problem, as it changed this week-end. Can you throw an eye on it?